# nav menu with icon html

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

Trying to make a responsive nav menu with icons in html. Its supposed to look like "image 1" but instead it looks like "image 2". Any ideas on how to fix it? it was working fine, but when I added icons to the nav menu, it went wrong. Thanks in advance.

[image: Image 1 is how its meant to look]

[image: Image 2 is how its not supposed to look]

**My code**
            
                
                    Home
                    My Work
                    About Me
                    Get in Touch

```
            </ul>

            <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;</a>


        </nav>

        <style>
        .icons1 {
            width: 40px;
            height: 30.5px;
            margin-left: 38px;
            background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png') no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            margin-top: 15px;
            float: left;

        }


        .current-item{
            width: 40px;
            height: 30.5px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/1024/sign-check-icon.png') no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;


        }
        /*----- Toggle Button -----*/
        .toggle-nav {
            display:none;
        }

        /*----- Menu -----*/
        @media screen and (min-width: 860px) {
            .menu {
                width:100%;
                height:100px;
                box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
                border-radius:3px;
                background:#303030;

            }
        }

        .menu ul {
            display:inline-block;

                margin-top:10px;
                height:90px;
        }

        .menu li {
            margin:0px 50px 0px 0px;
            float:left;
            list-style:none;
            font-size:17px;

            margin-top:10px;
            height:70px;
        }

        .menu li:last-child {
            margin-right:0px;
        }

        .menu a {
            text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            color:#777;
            transition:color linear 0.15s;
            text-decoration: none;

            line-height:6;
        }

        .menu a:hover, .menu .current-item a {
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#66a992;

        }



        /*----- Responsive -----*/
        @media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
            .wrap {
                width:90%;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
            .search-form input {
                width:120px;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
            .menu {
                position:relative;
                display:inline-block;
                width:100%;
                text-align:center;
        background-color:red;
            }

            .menu ul.active {
                display:none;
            }

            .menu ul {
                width:100%;
                position:absolute;
                top:120%;
                left:0px;
                padding:10px 0px;
                box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
                border-radius:3px;
                background:#303030;
            }




            .menu ul:after {
                width:0px;
                height:0px;
                position:absolute;
                top:0%;
                left:22px;
                content:'';
                transform:translate(0%, -100%);
                border-left:7px solid transparent;
                border-right:7px solid transparent;
                border-bottom:7px solid #303030;
            }

            .menu li {
                margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;
                float:none;
                display:block;
            }

            .menu a {
                display:block;

            }

            .toggle-nav {
                padding:20px;
                float:left;
                display:inline-block;
                box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
                border-radius:3px;
                background:#303030;
                text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                color:#777;
                font-size:20px;
                transition:color linear 0.15s;
            }

            .toggle-nav:hover, .toggle-nav.active {
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#66a992;
            }

            .search-form {
                margin:12px 0px 0px 20px;
                float:left;
            }

            .search-form input {
                box-shadow:-1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            }
        }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
                jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
                jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');

                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Your `line-height` is set to `6`. This means each line of text will exist in a row that is `6 x font-size`.

Comment: But if I dont add the line heigh, the words will be over the icon. Any ideas around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `white-space:nowrap;` to `.menu a`

```
.menu a {
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#777;
    transition:color linear 0.15s;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:6;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```